# Updating multiple mongo documents from single collection at once

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a mongo collection consisting multiple documents of some name value pair.

myCollection:

```
{"_id" : 1,"name" : "name1","value" : "val1"}

{"_id" : 2,"name" : "name2","value" : "val2"}

{"_id" : 3,"name" : "name3","value" : "val3"}
```

.
.
.
.
.
.100 records

now I want to update values of some of these records.
I am uploading an excel reading values from it and storing in a HashMap. Now how do I update these values on collection?

Comment: Could you post an example?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: what are condition on which you want to update it and do you want to do it with java

Comment: update those values whose name matches with uploaded names or  names in HashMap